# How would one state the negation of the absolute continuity definition

Tags: real-analysis, absolute-continuity

The definition of absolute continuity I'm using is the following (taken from Royden);

$f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$ provided that for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta >0$ such that for any finite disjoint collection $\{(a_k,b_k)\}_{k=1}^n$, if $\sum_{k=1}^nb_k-a_k < \delta$ then $\sum_{k=1}^n |f(b_k)-f(a_k)| < \epsilon$.

I tried putting "not" in front of the definition and following it through, and what I've come up with is;

There exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $\delta > 0$ there is some finite disjoint collection $\{(a_k,b_k)\}_{k=1}^n$ satisfying $\sum_{k=1}^nb_k-a_k < \delta$ and $\sum_{k=1}^n |f(b_k)-f(a_k)| \geq \epsilon$.

Chasing the "not" through the definition was a little sticky, so I just want to make sure I've stated it correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: It is extremely important to insert absolute value sign for $f(b_k)-f(a_k)$. Your definition is not equivalent to absolute continuity at all. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity for definition.

Comment: I added absolute value bars. It was just a typo.